# UI Automation Testscripts independent of deviceorientation

Tags: javascript, ios7, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Running testscripts of recorded ui-actions on the iPad with the Instrumentstool works only if the orientation of the iPad is same as it was by recording.

In horizontal-mode i have to access the button i want to tip like this:

```
UIATarger.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0].tap();
```

And upside down (horizontal "reversed") like this:

```
UIATarger.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[1].tap();
```

The buttons order has changed. Now i´m searching for a good solution to access that button without checking for the device orientation.

To search for a button name is not possible, because it has no name. In the **logTreeElement()** stands a **null** for the name.

I thought about checking the orientation and then placing the right ID, but thats not really smart...

Answer (score 0):

A) If you have access to the source code, my main answer would just be to go in and add the accessibilityLabels for all the elements that are necessary

B) Given you don't have the source code you could use the [UIATarget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/setDeviceOrientation) function setDeviceOrientation to properly set the orientation before running tests.